# Is voting limit inclusive of votes cast on meta?

Tags: support, up-votes, voting-limits

I get at times frustrating "voting limit reached" message. Does that count the votes I cast here on meta as well? Just preserving the scarce resource..

Comment: You can view the vote count in the top bar drop down menu (hover over where it says your user name). You can check how close you are to the vote limit and verify that your counts are different on meta/main site

Comment: @BenBrocka thanks, i did not notice even such silly things. I wonder how did I get 5 votes for this stupid question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let me thank you for taking the time to vote.

Second, no: votes between Meta and the main site are not combined; You have 30+10 votes on each (30 votes on anything, 10 additional votes for questions, only)

Your user profile on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661933/nawfal) and [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161537/nawfal) show your voting totals, verifying that they are separately counted.

EDIT: Also, note that votes on sites beyond the Trilogy seem to be counted separately from their site-specific Metas, as well. This can be seen on my profiles on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/163/andrew-barber) and [Meta.DBA](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/163/andrew-barber)

Comment: I should also add: It appears that your voting totals on your profile pages is cached to some degree, so keep in mind that the numbers shown there might not be exactly up-to-date.

Comment: where exactly in my profile can I see the vote count?

Comment: @nawfal at the very bottom right.

Answer (score 6):

The votes on meta are counted separately. So the amount of votes you have on meta is also limited, but voting on meta does not count towards your SO total (nor vice versa).